# Summing an array of numbers in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, arrays, sum

Basically. I have an array of numbers that I need to sum.  Here is my code:

```
- (NSInteger ) sumOfIntegersInArray: (NSArray *)array {
    NSInteger sum = 0;
    for (NSNumber *num in array) {
        sum += [num intValue];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

For some reason this doesn't work, but if I `NSLOG sum`, then it will print `100` (which is what the sum should be).  Why doesn't this work?

The error I keep getting is:

> "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion return 'NSInteger (aka 'long') from a function with a result type 'NSInteger *' (aka 'long *'); take the address with &

(If I let it correct my code to `return &sum`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: Why don't you have sum be an int?

Comment: Notice the `*` character in the error message.  What does `*` mean in C and Objective-C???

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Update your question with the line of code that actually causes the error.

Comment: BTW - use `[num integerValue]`, not `[num intValue]` with `NSInteger`.

Comment: seems ok to me. the problem is probably elsewhere

Comment: The problem is that the code you actually have says `- (NSInteger *) sumOfIntegersInArray: (NSArray *)array {` -- you're lying to us about the return type of the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger*) Sum {
    NSInteger sum = 0;
    for(NSNumber *num in array) {
        sum += [num intValue];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

I think you work like this.
You have miss on return type

change like this

```
- (NSInteger) Sum {
    NSInteger sum = 0;
    for(NSNumber *num in array) {
        sum += [num intValue];
    }
    return sum;
}
```